# Cannot Ping or ssh to my VM - OPEN NEBULA 4.12

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, opennebula

I'm really new in opennebula and i'm trying to configure both "the frontend and worker node" in a single server. I have attempted to follow the documentation here for configuring Open Nebula:

http://docs.opennebula.org/4.12/design_and_installation/quick_starts/qs_ubuntu_kvm.html

Unfortunately, i can't ping my virtual machine neither connect by ssh.

After several attempts i don't know where is the problem, anyone maybe know what can be the reason why i can't ping my VM???? Please

I have de following configuration:

**network inteface configuration:**

> ## The loopback network interface
>
> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto br0
>   iface br0 inet dhcp
>
> bridge_ports eth0
>
> bridge_fd 9
>
> bridge_hello 2
>
> bridge_maxage 12
>
> bridge_stp off

---

> **ifconfig -a**
>
> **br0**   Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:09:3d:13:49:a3
>   Direc. inet:158.42.104.139  Difus.:158.42.107.255  Másc: 255.255.252.0
>   ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
>   Paquetes RX:14171349 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>   Paquetes TX:33911 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>   colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0
>   Bytes RX:1215082462 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:4477371 (4.4 MB)
>
> **eth0**      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:09:3d:13:49:a3
>   ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
>   Paquetes RX:26205686 errores:0 perdidos:15549 overruns:0 frame:0
>   Paquetes TX:36656 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>   colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
>   Bytes RX:3187181063 (3.1 GB)  TX bytes:4892183 (4.8 MB)
>   Interrupción:24
>
> **virbr0**    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 8a:96:61:a8:2a:40
>   Direc. inet:192.168.122.1  Difus.:192.168.122.255  Másc:255.255.252.0
>   ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
>   Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>   Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>   colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0
>   Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

**my network template**

> NAME = "private simple"
>
> BRIDGE = br0
>
> AR = [
>   TYPE = IP4,
>   IP = 192.168.122.100,
>   SIZE = 5
>   ]
>
> ---

As you can see i can instantiate a new VM without problem:

> ID  USER     GROUP    NAME            STAT UCPU    UMEM HOST             TIME
>
> 10  oneadmin oneadmin my_vm_2_basic   ***runn***  1.0    512M localhost    5d  08h55

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve this since?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the network configuration on the vBox settings and restart the vm.

In the home page of the vBox app, press on the vm of you Nebula-running vm.

Then click the Settings button up-top.

Go to "Network".

Change the "Attached to" toggle to "Bridged Network". Click "OK"...

Then restart your nebula vm.

To connect to your vm via an external terminal type the following line on your linux terminal:

```
ssh levelXX@nebula-vm-ip
```

For Windows machines you can use "PuTTy".

Good luck!